# GetMouseMovePointsEx in C++ program keeps returning -1 (no point in history?)

Tags: c++, winapi

I have this simple Windows C++ program using the Win32 API:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h> // GET_Y_LPARAM
#include <string>

#include <iostream>

// clang++ -std=c++23 mouse.cc -o mouse.exe -luser32 -lgdi32

// Handler for WM_MOUSEMOVE
void OnMouseMove(HWND hwnd, int x, int y) {
    MOUSEMOVEPOINT inputPoint;
    ZeroMemory(&inputPoint, sizeof(inputPoint)) ;
    inputPoint.x = x;// & 0x0000FFFF ;
    inputPoint.y = y;// & 0x0000FFFF ;
    //std::cerr << x << " " << y << std::endl;
    //inputPoint.time = GetMessageTime(); // Use the time of the current message
    //inputPoint.dwExtraInfo = GetMessageExtraInfo();

    MOUSEMOVEPOINT points[64]; // Adjust size based on your needs
    int pointsRetrieved = GetMouseMovePointsEx(sizeof(MOUSEMOVEPOINT), &inputPoint, points, 64, GMMP_USE_DISPLAY_POINTS);
    if (pointsRetrieved > 0) {
         std::cerr << pointsRetrieved << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        //std::cerr << "Error retrieving mouse move points. Error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int MyWindowCreation(HINSTANCE hInstance) {
    const char CLASS_NAME[] = "Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = {};

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        CLASS_NAME,
        "Mouse Position Display",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        case WM_MOUSEMOVE: {
            int xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
            int yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
            OnMouseMove(hwnd, xPos, yPos);
            std::string mousePosition = "X: " + std::to_string(xPos) + ", Y: " + std::to_string(yPos);
            SetWindowText(hwnd, mousePosition.c_str());
            //OnMouseMove(hwnd, xPos, yPos);
            break;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int main() {
    HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    MyWindowCreation(hInstance);
    return 0;
    
}
```

I put that together to try to get mouse data using `GetMouseMovePointsEx()`. I tried different things, but I keep getting `pointsRetrieved = -1` and the error message says that it can't find the mouse data for that position in the buffer.

I looked at the [MS documentation for this function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmousemovepointsex). Sadly, the code they provided couldn't compile (it doesn't respect the function signature). At least this code compiles. I tried with `& 0x0000FFFF` and without when setting `x` and `y`, but it makes no difference. The coordinates passed from `WM_MOUSEMOVE` are correct.

It must be something simple!? Can it be that somehow it would be hardware-related? I mean maybe on some configuration, Windows just doesn't record the mouse history? I am on Windows 10.

Is there an alternative, better way to do this? Is this an outdated method?

Comment: Not reading the manual? *An application should call this function using the mouse coordinates received from the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message **and convert them to screen coordinates.***

Comment: WM_MOUSEMOVE supplies client coordinates, GetMouseMovePointsEx requires screen coordinates, you need to convert.

Comment: I agree though, the MS supplied code is poor.

Comment: @273K. Thanks for your input. Really appreciate. As explained to Remy (below), where I come from (3D world) screen coordinates mean top/left corner of your actual framebuffer, that is the window - minus title bar. So with this written in stone in my brain, I could not think any other how). Hopefully you helped me unplug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I put that together to try to get mouse data using `GetMouseMovePointsEx()`. I tried different things, but I keep getting `pointsRetrieved = -1` and **the error message says that it can't find the mouse data for that position in the buffer**.

That is because you are giving it the wrong coordinates to begin with.

Per the `GetMouseMovePointsEx()` documentation, it wants the input point expressed in **screen coordinates**:

> [in] lppt
>
> Type: LPMOUSEMOVEPOINT
>
> A pointer to a MOUSEMOVEPOINT structure containing valid mouse coordinates (**in screen coordinates**). It may also contain a time stamp.

But, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` provides you with a mouse point expressed in **client coordinates** instead:

> lParam
>
> The low-order word specifies the x-coordinate of the cursor. **The coordinate is relative to the upper-left corner of the client area.**
>
> The high-order word specifies the y-coordinate of the cursor. **The coordinate is relative to the upper-left corner of the client area.**

Inside your `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler, you need to use [`ClientToScreen()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-clienttoscreen) to convert the provided client coordinates into screen coordinates before passing them to `GetMouseMovePointsEx()`.

The `GetMouseMovePointsEx()` documentation even says as much:

> An application should call this function using the mouse coordinates received from the WM_MOUSEMOVE message **and convert them to screen coordinates**.

Comment: Well I did read the docs( but screen coordinates for me since I come from the world of 3D, are coordinates in relation to the top / left corner of your actual framebuffer. If this means in relation to the top / left coordinates of your screen, there was no way my brain could think about this). That's why i got it wrong. Thanks for pointing it to me. Just got confused by terminology that has a different meaning where I come from). Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: @user18490 [Window Coordinate System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/window-coordinate-system)